# Details in sparse indexing

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have some code which uses sparse indexing (and there's no way that I can get around that). I run this in a function, and use it for two problems, where the sizes of all the variables involved do not change. However, for one problem, the sparse indexing part takes 5 seconds, and for the other, takes 25 seconds.

I checked the size of every variable involved, and they are the same for both problems. I also checked that xv is a full matrix for both problem types.

So, anyone else ever run into something weird like this? Any ideas as to why this would happen? Mainly I am trying to make the code more efficient, and while 5 seconds is ok for my particular application, 25 seconds (especially when I can't explain it) is very bad.

Edit: Here is a link to a photo that profiles this weird behavior. The runtime values were recorded on the third run to ensure that the size of X is also not changing. And I did check that xv is a dense (not sparse) matrix both times.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i41j6afanzbjdyg/weird_bcd_thing.png?dl=0

Thanks so much for any help!

Code below (runs in a for loop). If I use ptype = 1, then it's 5 seconds, ptype = 3 is 25 seconds.

```
clvec = cliques{k};
xcurr = full(X(clvec));
xv = reshape(xcurr - Z(offset_index(k) + 1 : offset_index(k) + ncl^2),ncl,ncl);

%these two functions both take a dense symmetric matrix and return a dense symmetric matrix, and in both cases the size is the same for a given k.
if ptype == 1
     xv = proj_PSD(xv,0,0); 
elseif ptype == 3
     xv = proj_Schoenberg(xv,0);
end
Xd = vec(xv) - xcurr;

%THIS IS THE WEIRD LINE            
tic
X(clvec) = xv;
toc;
```

Comment: That can most certainly happen if the number of indices you have is very large.  It can also happen if you are trying to index into `X` with indices that access locations beyond the original size of `X`.  You would thus be dynamically expanding the size of `X` which can thus factor into the time it takes to complete the statement.  When `ptype = 3`, what is the size of `clvec`?  Also, what is the maximum value inside `clvec` (i.e. `max(clvec(:));` ) and what is the size of `X` before the "weird line"?

Comment: I checked to make sure, the ACTUAL VALUES in both cases of clvec are the same. So, both length(clvec) and max(clvec(:)) should be the same. The size of X is the same also. (I mean they grow in the loop but they are the same for a given k.)

Comment: OK.  How many elements are in `clvec`?

Comment: sorry I just edited my comment. basically everything is the same except the functions proj_SDP and proj_Schoenberg, which output the same type and size of variable.

Comment: That is weird indeed.  Did you try the suggestion below where you convert your matrix into `full` and index into the matrix that way?  The fact that your matrix is `sparse` could also factor into timing

Comment: That won't work, because we want this to scale for matrices of size 100,000 x 100,000. If it didn't work just because of the sparse indexing, we'd accept that and move on, but the weird thing is that it works for one problem but not another, so I was just hoping it was because of something silly. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

In the 'WEIRD LINE' : X(clvec) = xv;
You are using a random access to a sparse matrix. 
This access in a sparse matrix is not constant and depends on its data. The time is may depend on the matrix values and the indices you are trying to access.
This is not the case in regular matrix, where you usually get a stable access time, and faster.
In order to assure a stable constant access try to change the implementation based on your specific matrix usage, try to avoid values assign by random access.
See next code for as a reference:

---

```
X = sparse(randi(100,50,1),randi(100,50,1),randn(1),100,100);
for i=1:10000
    rand_inds{i} = randperm(10000,100);
end
for i=1:100
    ti = tic;
    X(rand_inds{i}) = 3;
    to_X(i) = toc(ti);    
end

Xf = full(X);
for i=1:100
    ti = tic;
    Xf(rand_inds{i}) = 3;
    to_Xf(i) = toc(ti);    
end

figure;plot(to_X);hold on;plot(to_Xf,'r');
```

Comment: Yeah I get that there are differences between working with sparse and dense matrix. The weird thing here is that the matrix is sparse for both cases, yet behaving differently, and none of the usual suspects (size of index, type of data) are the problem. So I was just wondering if there was something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem! I'm posting the answer because I think it's interesting.

One thing I didn't mention in the question is that the loop goes from k = 1 to k = L, and for ptype = 3, we add one more step, and that's assigning all the diagonal indices to 0:

```
X(diag_index) = 0
```

where diag_index is computed ahead of time.

The problem is, instead of just assigning the values to 0, MATLAB will automatically discard these indices, and the next loop, when accessing diagonal indices, it has to re-allocate for X. So, I changed that line to

```
X(diag_index) = eps;
```

and now they both run equally fast!  (It's not the best solution, since that's going to be a source of error later, but there's no more mystery!)

The answer is never what you think it would be...